# How to get Google Apps groups to accept my emails?

Tags: email, spam, g-suite, email-bounces, google

I've been running a mailserver for myself and some others for quite some time now.  Just recently (since moving to a new host) we've started seeing bounces when we send mail to email addresses that are "groups" on "Google Apps" -- we can email normal gmail and google apps addresses just fine, but when we email a group we get the:

> Your email to group ... was rejected due to spam classification.

I'm not sure what I can do here.  I have SPF set up and passing, I have DKIM set up and passing, and every other host (including normal Gmail) accepts my mail without issue.  Is there some trick to convincing these addresses that I'm not SPAM?  (Since they're often company support email addresses, it's even more annoying.)

Comment: seems to be a known issue with google apps groups - check https://support.google.com/a/answer/2567001?hl=en  and https://support.google.com/a/answer/168383 or  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/OTbG4HpTB-o

Comment: @Sachin I've seen those of course, but none of them offer any useful advice (they say add SPF, but of course I have SPF set up and passing already...)

Comment: I've (just) used this form https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2696779?hl=en to submit a wrong classification report. I don't suppose anything will change, but I've had positive results when doing something similar with Hotmail, AOL, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Postmaster Tools (https://postmaster.google.com) to add/verify your domain.

Larry